# What's the best way to create a FAQ page for ios app

Tags: ios

Many ios apps contain a FAQ or How to use page, when loaded, will display some FAQs in text format. The content is loaded from remote server rather than built in so the contents can be updated anytime with flexibility.

What's the best way to implement this type of page? My app does not contain any server side function except this page so I am really looking for a cheap (or free) way instead of renting a server just for this. Also, my FAQs will be static HTML.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: [do you mean this?](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?page=1&q=tutorial)

Comment: @FahimParkar If you use Instagram, I mean creating a FAQ function similar to what Instagram does. Of course, my FAQ page is only one single page rather than multiple in hierarchy. But the idea is similar. Also, I tried to put some text in a webpage created by google sites. But the webpage looks (rather ugly) like a normal webpage displayed on ios rather than good looking native ios page.

Comment: if that is the case, you will need css to to make it more better in look...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to display an HTML page is to use a `UIWebView` as the main view of your view controller and set its URL or file-path using the `loadRequest()` method of your view.

You can use this method for both remote FAQs (in this case you'll set an URL) and local  and static ones for which you'll use a path to the file included in your project.